# Find report file outside of Application.StartupPath or bin folder

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

My Crystal Report is located outside of `Application.StartupPath` and the bin folder - in a tree folder:

```
MainFolder
  - CrystalReport_here_which_is_Sales_report.rpt
bin 'folder
  - DebugFolder
    - inside debug folder is the application startup
```

I used this code but it cannot locate the file - How can I resolve this?

```
rpt.Load(Application.StartupPath & "\Sales_Report.rpt")
```

Comment: Pop the report inside your debug folder if you want to run whilst debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem with a relative path (code in vb.net) :

```
Dim CRPath as String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.StartupPath) & "\..\..\MainFolder\"
rpt.Load(CRPath & "Sales_Report.rpt")
```